# Passing self into a class method in Python

Tags: python

I'm creating some generic functions and want to call instance methods with a set of parameters, but also have access to self within the method.

```
class Test:

  aggregation = [{'function_name': 'functionA', 'parameters': {'weight': 10}},..]
  generic_parameters = {'_id': 1234} # all things generic to the user
  version = 0.7

  def functionA(self, _id=None, weight=1.0):
    print(self.version)
    pass

  def functionB(..):
    pass

  def functionC(..):
    pass

  function_dict = {'functionA': functionA, 'functionB': functionB, 'functionC': functionC} # Push all functions into here
  
  def __init__(self, _id=None):
    self._id = _id

  def s(self):
    for s_score in self.aggregation:
      function_name = sub_score['function_name']
      parameters = sub_score['parameters']
      sub_parameters = self.generic_parameters
      sub_parameters.update(parameters)
      op = self.function_dict[function_name](**sub_parameters)
      print(op)
```

Running with:

```
test = Test()
test.s()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: functionA() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

on the following line:

```
op = self.function_dict[function_name](**sub_parameters)
```

I have tried one suggestion using `gatattr` but there appears an issue that self is not being passed into `functionA`.

Replacing the code calling the functionA etc with

```
op = getattr(self, function_name)(**parameters)
```

But in the functionA called by this, the following is shown as an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '_id'
```

Is the `getattr(self, function_name)(**parameters)`, not passing in self. If not, how can this be achieved?

Comment: You might be better off doing `getattr(self, function_name)(**sub_parameters)`. Your current code is getting functions before the class has been instantiated so you need to pass `self` explicitly

Comment: The functions in `function_dict` were retrieved directly from the class, rather than from any particular instance of the class (indeed, no instances of the class could have existed at that point in time).  That makes them *unbound methods* - you have to explicitly supply a `self` parameter when calling them.

Comment: @jasonharper Can you suggest what that call looks like please. I have tried the `getattr()` call but this doesn't seem to pass in `self`.

Comment: `op = self.function_dict[function_name](self, **sub_parameters)`

Comment: @tripleee. This is leading to the following error: `TypeError: functionA() got multiple values for argument 'weight'`

Comment: @triplee AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '_id', when I write as you suggest.

Comment: Once I correct the obvious typo and add the `self` parameter as suggested by @tripleee, it works fine for me.  Although you're going to find `self.generic_parameters` collecting some garbage on every call.